# Determine which button was clicked inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have the following HTML code (I can’t change it) and I want to determine which button of these, from A to Z, was clicked. Any idea how I can do this? Here is what I tried, but I always get the result "alphabet". I could also write:

```js
document.getElementById("A").onclick = button;
document.getElementById("B").onclick = button;
```

and so on inside `myMain` function but is there a simple solution?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function myMain() {
      document.getElementById("alphabet").onclick = button;
    }

    function button() {
      alert(this.id);
    }

    window.onload = myMain;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="alphabet">
    <button id="A">A</button> <button id="B">B</button> <button id="C">C</button> <button id="D">D</button> <button id="E">E</button> <button id="F">F</button>
    <button id="G">G</button> <button id="H">H</button> <button id="I">I</button> <button id="J">J</button> <button id="K">K</button> <button id="L">L</button>
    <button id="M">M</button> <button id="N">N</button> <button id="O">O</button> <button id="P">P</button> <button id="Q">Q</button> <button id="R">R</button>
    <button id="S">S</button> <button id="T">T</button> <button id="U">U</button> <button id="V">V</button> <button id="W">W</button> <button id="X">X</button>
    <button id="Y">Y</button> <button id="Z">Z</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use event object

```js
window.onload = myMain;

function myMain() {
  document.getElementById("alphabet").onclick = buton;
}

function buton(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    alert(e.target.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="alphabet">
  <button id="A">A</button>
  <button id="B">B</button>
  <button id="C">C</button>
  <button id="D">D</button>
  <button id="E">E</button>
  <button id="F">F</button>
  <button id="G">G</button>
  <button id="H">H</button>
  <button id="I">I</button>
  <button id="J">J</button>
  <button id="K">K</button>
  <button id="L">L</button>
  <button id="M">M</button>
  <button id="N">N</button>
  <button id="O">O</button>
  <button id="P">P</button>
  <button id="Q">Q</button>
  <button id="R">R</button>
  <button id="S">S</button>
  <button id="T">T</button>
  <button id="U">U</button>
  <button id="V">V</button>
  <button id="W">W</button>
  <button id="X">X</button>
  <button id="Y">Y</button>
  <button id="Z">Z</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you +1

Answer (score 2):

Event handler functions are fired in the context of the element to which they are bound, not the element which was used to trigger the event.

You need to capture the event object:

```js
function button(event){
  // …
}
```

and then look at the target of the click:

```js
const element = event.target;
```

You can then look at that element’s `id`:

```js
console.log(element.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Code Explained below :

```
 alert(e.target.id);
```

**You can use `e.target.id.` e.target represents DOM object and you can access all its property and methods.**

```js
        window.onload = myMain;
        function myMain() {
            document.getElementById("alphabet").onclick = buton;
        }
      
function buton(e) {
   
    alert(e.target.id);

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="alphabet">
        <button id="A">A</button> <button id="B">B</button> <button id="C">C</button> <button id="D">D</button> <button id="E">E</button> <button id="F">F</button> 
        <button id="G">G</button> <button id="H">H</button> <button id="I">I</button> <button id="J">J</button> <button id="K">K</button> <button id="L">L</button> 
        <button id="M">M</button> <button id="N">N</button> <button id="O">O</button> <button id="P">P</button> <button id="Q">Q</button> <button id="R">R</button> 
        <button id="S">S</button> <button id="T">T</button> <button id="U">U</button> <button id="V">V</button> <button id="W">W</button> <button id="X">X</button> 
        <button id="Y">Y</button> <button id="Z">Z</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/3u42ab9b/) is the working fiddle

Comment: This will throw an exception because `e` is not defined.

Comment: @Quentin please check entire code.tried in fiddle as well

Comment: Re edit: "Just change one line" —you've changed more than one line.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for pointing that out..i think OP has code:alert(this.id); , which with some code modifications i implemented with    alert(e.target.id); thats the reason behind that reply.. anyway will edit that line if getting mistaken,,

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttonElements = document.querySelectorAll('#alphabet button');
for (var i = 0;i < buttonElements.length;i++){
    buttonElements[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        alert(this.getAttribute('id'));
    });
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Jquery instead

HTML

```
<div>
   <input type="button" id="A"/>
   <input type="button" id="B"/>
 </div>
```

Javascript

```
 $("button").Click(function(){
       alert($(this).attr("id"))
  })
```